# Is there JavaScript Object.assign() analogue in Java?

Tags: java, object, merge

So, in JavaScript Object.assign() can "merge" two (or more as I know) objects.

For example, we have `{a: "b", c: "d"}` and `{c: "a", p: "e"}`. After merging we will get a new object `{a: "b", c: "a", p: "e"}`.
If both objects have children objects with same key, the function will merge children.

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Even though you're referencing JavaScript's `Object.assign`, the question is not about JavaScript so the [tag:javascript] tag is not appropriate.

Comment: you didn't show your JS code,  Object.assign()  has some has some subtleties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java, unlike JavaScript, is *strictly typed*. You can't create ad hoc objects such as the examples in your question.

In situations where you want to do something along those lines, you'd use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementation (`HashMap` and similar). `Map` has several methods for doing things that are similar to `Object.assign` such as [`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)).

```
Map<String, String> target = new HashMap<>();
target.putAll(source1);
target.putAll(source2);
```

Or

```
Map<String, String> target = new HashMap<>(source1);
target.putAll(source2);
```

Full Example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Map<String, String> source1 = new HashMap<>();
        source1.put("a", "b");
        source1.put("c", "d");
        Map<String, String> source2 = new HashMap<>();
        source2.put("c", "a");
        source2.put("p", "e");

        Map<String, String> target = new HashMap<>();
        target.putAll(source1);
        target.putAll(source2);

        for (var entry : target.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```